# Cannot Save or Use Binding Model Data on OnPost Passed By Form in Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I have a problem in EditUserProfile in razor page, so there is no problem showing the user information in the page, but when I press edit button, I get user information through the form but I can't save or user it.

**The code**

[image: here is the code]

**The page**

[image: and the page]

I even tried to save the username in variable but here is what happens

**userName PassedBy Form**

[image: userName PassedBy Form]

**trying to save it**

[image: trying to save it]

[userRepository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWYKG.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where it states that you should not use links or pasted pictures in your question. Please paste in your code and use the appropriate formatting. This will make answering your question a lot easier for other users.

Comment: Can you show me ```_userRepository.Save()``` ?

Comment: @RajuMelveetilpurayil , its just _context.SaveChanges() , I Get the user in OnPost Method and I replace the fields that user has edited in the form , the main problem is that on OnPost method I Get the _User with all edited fields but I cant use or save it, for example the userID return 1 but when I give it to GetUserByID its null, so I could never save a null user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,your _User.UserName ="saeed_01",and username is null in your picture,this is because this line of code has not been executed yet。When you excute it and go to the next line of code,you can see the username is "saeed_01".

And if you want to save the edited user.I think you can change your `Save` in `UserRepository` like this:

```
public async Task Save(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and change

```
_userRepositiory.Save();
```

to

```
await _userRepositiory.Save(user);
```

**Update:**

here is the endpoint in your code:
[image]

you try to change the endpoint to here:
[image]

And then you can see the username is not null

Here is a demo:
User:

```
 public class User {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            User _User = new User { UserId = 1, UserName = "sss" };
            var username = _User.UserName;
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: no the line has executed, the break point is at the end of the OnPost method, I never got the chance to save it, I get the _User with all edited fields as you can see in the picture but I cant save or use it, like the UserName is "saeed_01" but when I try to save it in the variable its null, or when I try to find the user with GetUserByID , the userID is 1 but when I Pass it to the method its null, I want get the user and replace edited fields and save it

Comment: See my update in my answer,in your code,you try to change the endpoint,and then after you executed `var username=_User.UserName`,try to see the username.

Comment: hey thank you its been a week i had this problem, you were right that line didnt execute, I traced it and the Model State was not valid so the rest of the codes werent execute, cause the user model had some other fields that were required and I didnt fill them, I just wanted to edit some of the fields, so I made a ViewModel and set the properties that I wanted to edit and it is working, Thank you for your time and your help

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that _User and var user in the method is pointing to the same object in memory. I can't be sure because not all code is visible.

It all depends on the code in the `userRepository`. The ORM you are using could have some kind of cache and this could cause some weird behavior.

In the OnGet method clone the user, that you get from `GetUserByUserId` to the _User property.

```
public void OnGet()
{
   var user = _userRepositiory.GetUserByUserName(HttpContext.User.GetUserId());
    _User = new User(){
        // set all properties here
    };
}
```

Comment: thank u for your time, I did what you said but no difference, still I cant save it, it does not return null but when I try to use the userName for example I cant, The GetUserById works in OnGet but it doesnt on OnPost,here is the userRepository Code  <br /> public User GetUserByUserID(int userID)
        {
            return _context.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == userID);
        } , im really sorry I dont know how to work with stackOverFlow its my first time